# Send to multiple database input type = "radio"

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to create a input type = "radio", where it will be multiple polls and will store the answers in the database according to the selected option.

How could I do to insert all polling responses into a same table.

Below is the HTML code with the radios.

```html
      <tr>
       <td>
           
   <div class="radio">
  <input type="hidden" id="questao" name="questao" value="84">
 <label><input type="radio" value="291" name="84">Ótimo</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="292" name="84">Bom</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="293" name="84">Regular</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="294" name="84">Fraco</label>
   </div>
      
       
       </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
       <td>
        
     <div class="radio">
 <input type="hidden" id="85" name="85" value="85">
 <label><input type="radio" value="295" name="85">Ótima</label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="296" name="85">Boa</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="297" name="85">Regular</label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="298" name="85">Fraca</label>
      </div>
        
       
       </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
       
        
    <div class="radio">
 <input type="hidden" id="86" name="86" value="86">
 <label><input type="radio" value="299" name="86">Ótimo</label>
 <label><input type="radio" value="300" name="86">Bom</label>
       <label><input type="radio" value="301" name="86">Regular</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="302" name="86">Fraco</label>
     </div>
        
       
       </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
       
        
     <div class="radio">
  <input type="hidden" id="87" name="87" value="87">
  <label><input type="radio" value="303" name="87">Ótimo</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="304" name="87">Bom</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="305" name="87">Regular</label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="306" name="87">Fraco</label>
         </div>
        

       </td>
      </tr>
```

Below a function made in laravel inside a controller

```
public function enviando(Request $request)
            {
                $date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
                $pegar_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

                if($_POST = '84'){
                    $questao_id = '84';
    }
    if($_POST = '85'){
        $questao_id = '85';
    }
    if($_POST = '86'){
        $questao_id = '86';
    }
    if($_POST = '87'){
        $questao_id = '87';
    }

                DB::table('eventos_avaliacoes_participantes')
                        ->insert(['avaliacao_id' => "2",
                                 'nome' => $request->input('nome'),
                                 'email' => $request->input('email'),
                                 'sexo' => $request->input('sexo'),
                                 'comentarios' => $request->input('comentarioevento'),
                                 'ip' => $pegar_ip,
                                 'created' => $date]);


                $id = '171';
                $opcao = $request->input('84');
                DB::table('eventos_avaliacoes_participantes_opcoes')
                        ->insert(['opcao_id' => $opcao,
                                 'questao_id' => $questao_id,
                                 'participante_id' => $id+1]);






            return redirect('sucesso');

            }
```

Comment: You'll want to take the time to de-indent your code a little so it's not shoved so far to the right you can't read it.

Comment: ok @tadman,done.

Comment: Without going into your problem $questao_id will always be 87 as you are assigning instead of comparing  in your if statements if($_POST = '85') VS IF($_POST === '85').